# Why is the .capitalize() method not retained but if I do .sort() it is? How do I retain it?

Tags: python

I want to have the capitalize method run on my string then print it out, but it prints the original string. However, when I do other methods, such as sort, it prints a new, sorted list?
Why is this and how can I get a capitalized string without having the capitalize method as part of my print statement?

Input:

```
cat = ['cat', 'bird']
cat.sort()
print(cat)

cat = ['cat', 'bird']
cat[0].capitalize()
print(cat)
```

Output:

```
['bird', 'cat']
['cat', 'bird']
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python. `capitalize()` returns a new string, it can't modify the original string.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the sort works on the instance and is a function, whereas `capitalize` is a `return` method that does something then returns it, if you want to change a variable to the capitalised version use this:

```
cat = ['cat', 'bird']
cat[0] = cat[0].capitalize()
print(cat)
```

Using the `sort` doesn't return something, whereas capitalise does return something, you didn't assign the new value to the item in the list.

Comment: You have it backwards. `sort()` works in place, it doesn't return anything. `capitalize()` returns a new string.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I didn't realise I have fixed it now.

Comment: You still say **This is because the sort works on the instance and is a return method,**